# System architecture advice for a dual interface online/mobile marketplace

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, architecture, amazon-web-services

My startup is building an online/mobile labor marketplace where there will be a business interface for businesses posting jobs and we distribute these jobs through a mobile interface for users. We use Rails, REST, Amazon RDS & EC2 and mysql.

My question is: from an architecture standpoint on the server-side does it make sense to?:

a) Have 2 applications one serving the web interface and one acting as the server-side (API) for the mobile interface and both communicating via the DB and via 2 different EC2 instances

b) Try to build one comprehensive application serving both interfaces

Any opinion and perspective on pros and cons would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Web Services are giving you a few tools to make your architecture simpler, more robust and scalable, if you break down your system into smaller, simpler and independent components.

Since you have a set different [sizes of instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/) from micro to extra large (and a few sizes of extra large), you have the flexibility to mix each service type to the appropriate size, configuration, software dependencies, update cycle etc. It will make the life of the developers, testers and administrators much easier.

You also have the ability to scale and even [auto-scale](http://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/) each layer and service independently. If you have more users of one of the interfaces, or the other, or increase in data size that is fed through one of the interfaces, you can scale only the relevant service. It will save you the complexity and cost of scaling the full system as a whole.

Another characteristic of AWS is the ability to scale up, down, out and in based on your need. For example, if one of the interface has more users on working weekdays and fewer on weekends, you can scale down this interface for the weekend or night, saving 50% of your computation costs for this instances. In this regards, you can switch from the on-demand model for the more static interfaces to [reserved instances](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/reserved-instances/), saving again 50% of your costs.

To allow communication between the different interfaces you can use your DB, but you also have a few more options based on your use case. One option is to use Queueing system as [SQS](http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/). The queue is used as a buffer between the interfaces, reducing the risk of failure of one component (software bug, hardware failure...), affecting the whole system. Another option for inter interfaces communication, that is more tuned to performance is to use in-memory cache. AWS are offering [ElasticCache](http://aws.amazon.com/elasticache/) as such service. It can be more efficient than updating such transient data for short period of time and with high load.

I see no long term cons, other than the quick (and dirty) implementation of a single service on a single machine.

Answer (score 0):

The overall goal should be to have most amount of code common between the mobile and web application. Otherwise you are looking at maintenance headaches where you will end up e.g. fixing bugs, or adding features at two places at minimum.

Ideally everything below the front end should be common. The web UI should itself be calling the server side APIs that you are going to need for mobile application. And most amount of logic should be put into these APIs, leaving only presentation details to the UI. This is as prescribed by many patterns such as MVC.

I have a mobile site and desktop site running myself. The codebase is exactly the same at PHP level. Only the smarty templates are different between the two. Granted that mobile application is different from mobile site, but the basic principles still apply.